# Sending accessibility events in android- dispatchpopulateaccessibilityevent() not working properly

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

i want to send an accessibilityevent message in an application and i have the following code:

```
       AccessibilityManager manager = (AccessibilityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
        if (manager.isEnabled()) {
            AccessibilityEvent event = AccessibilityEvent.obtain();
            event.setEventType(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT);
            event.setPackageName(event.getPackageName());
            event.setClassName(event.getClassName());
            event.getText().add("turnflagtrue");
            event.setEnabled(true);
            if(dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event))
                Log.v("Synchronize","success?");
            else
                Log.v("Synchronize","Dispatch returned false");
            manager.sendAccessibilityEvent(event);
        }
```

and event though dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent returns true i don't get any accessibility Event with Type Announcement. Event the last line that supposed to send an accessibilityevent doesn't send anything.
I also tried to change the getApplicationContext to getBaseContext or this but i still have the same issue. 
Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: Is your application active when you try to send the event? Are you running TalkBack or some other accessibility service? Have you tried turning on verbose logging in TalkBack Settings and watching the event stream?

Comment: Yes my app is active. It have put the event inside onCreate(). I use my own accessibility service as described in [here](http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html) and here is the code in my service for detecting the events:   @Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {    if(event.getEventType()!=AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT) 
     return;
else
     Log.v("Synchronize", event.toString());

Comment: Are you sure that your custom service is receiving TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT events in general? You can test this by using View.announceForAccessibility(String) from a simple test app.